# How to Bend an Object Back Onto Itself

Tags: modeling

Man I'm rusty tonight. I want to bend and twist this object so that it folds back flat on itself (without overlapping), then rotates out 30-degrees (kind of like a twisted V-shape).

Currently the object is a long rectangle with a center loop where I want to make the bend.

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Could you show how should the 'rotates out 30-degrees' look like? Cheers ;)

Comment: Hello, as Jachym says it's not clear, also do you want to animate the shape bending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Due to [a quirk of the *Simple Deform* modifier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMYccraiLQU), if you want to bend objects in the X or Y axes, you need your geometry oriented in the Z direction. You also need enough geometry in that direction (i.e. loop cuts) so it has something to bend. In this case, this means we need our starting rectangular box to be vertical like shown below. Do note that that when I say "vertical", I mean the mesh itself is vertical in *Edit mode*, if you simply rotated the box in your screenshot 90° in *Object mode*, it wouldn't work. If you can't have your mesh oriented like that for some reason, you could also employ a properly rotated *Empty* and use that as the *Origin* in your modifier settings.

[image]

Now we bend our box 180° around the Y axis, but of course the curve of the bend is too wide for it to fold on itself flat as you want. To achieve that, we can use the *Limits* under the *Restrictions* section of the modifier. What you need to be aware here is that if you want the two edges of your rectangle to align perfectly, you need to make sure that the values you enter as *Limits* add up to $1.00$. Here I'm using $0.47$ and $0.53$, for instance. The closer those values are to each other, the narrower the bend gets:

[image]

Finally, to get the "twisted V-shape" effect you rotate the mesh in *Edit mode* around the X axis. To get a 30° deviation in total, you would rotate 15°:

[image]

Comment: very nice answer, learned something new today :))

Comment: Perfect answer thank you!!

Comment: Now I’m going to need to do this to the same object again, a few more times in fact. My plan is to extrude one of the ends the same length as the original object, and bend and twist again, exactly how you have done the first time.  I guess what limits my understanding is how to bend an object from a point, depending on its axis.  How would you do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://i.imgur.com/u1IWzLu.png It might not be feasible to keep it procedural with just a Simple Deform (what I did here is pretty rough under the hood even if it might look OK in the screenshot). Maybe ask it as a new question, along with a rough sketch of what you need?